# Reference error thrown in execution, but not shown in visual studio error messages

Tags: c#, reference, ext.net

So i have referenced ext.net in as assembly to a `.aspx` site. then i copied the site and the corresponding code behind and adjusted classnames and namespaces. i have been staying in the same solution. now when i reference, like on the old site:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>
```

and debug, the old site is shown correctly (as i didn't change anything to it), but the "copied" site logs a `uncaught reference error` to developer-console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined
```

**EDIT:**
the copy and the original are two interfaces to the same site --> they are in the same folder and the same project

**EDIT 2:**
after checking and rechecking from cleaning the solution to any possible rebuild i found, that default_admin (the Copy) is not included to the solution, even though i did so, seems an Update took the reference out. now i got the problem, that "Ext.Net.xml" cannot be copied to "bin/Ext.Net.xml" furthermore the type from the code-behind is not loaded properly

**EDIT 3:**
well. now i have a web.config file, that is likewise to that of a working component also including the ext.net framework, i guess it may really be a client-side javascript issue, but even after installing NuGet the Error occurs, now we are at the old Error again. also i have "copied" the site by creating a new site to fix a different error.

**EDIT 4:**
Also a new Checkout and restarting from 0 didn't help

**EDIT 5:**
Restart from -1 helped until i added RecordFields with default Values to a grid. it seems the quoting of tag properties is not totally correct for the conversion to javascript, see
[Default Value in RecordField throws JavaScript error on execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726669/default-value-in-recordfield-throws-javscript-error-on-execute)

Comment: I'm assuming ext.net is a DLL. Where is it located?

Comment: ../../../lib/ext/ext_community/ext.net.dll ,even though the reference is absolute in the project. the problem is, that a different page in the same folder references without any problems to the same dll

Comment: When you're making a copy, where is the DLL? My guess is that it simply can't find it. You will likely need to deploy the referenced DLL to the same folder with your web site DLLs or place it in the GAC.

Comment: the copy and the original are in the same folder and the same solution so this cannot be the problem

Comment: Define "copied". If they're in the same folder, how was anything "copied?"

Comment: take a file named "default.aspx", the corresponding code-behind "default.aspx.cs", as well as the designer "default.aspx.designer.cs", copy them, directly paste them and replace " - Copy" / "(2) by "_admin" and refactor the class and file-dependencies to code-behind. then make the whole thing throw no more critical errors and execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a client-side JavaScript error.

My guess is you're missing the required sections of the Web.config. Please review section IV of the following README.txt and triple check you have added all the Ext.NET related configuration to your projects Web.config file.

http://examples.ext.net/#/Getting_Started/Introduction/README/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Installing using NeGet will automatically configure all these sections for you. It might be an option to try if you're still running into issues.

Comment: the problem is, another file in the same directory refernces to the same assembly without problems --> the Web.config is not the problem

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined` is a client-side error. It means the .js files have not been loaded properly. If you create a brand new test website, then install with NuGet, that site should work properly. Then you need to determine the differences between the two applications.

Comment: the problem is, after creating a brand new webform the error still occurs. NuGet is installed and still Visual Studio returns no errors.