# Default Value in RecordField throws JavaScript error on execute

Tags: javascript, grid, store, default-value, ext.net

Adding following Record Fields to the GridPanel Store makes the site throw a JavaScript Error  
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` to the Chrome Console

```
<ext:RecordField Name="listname" AllowBlank="false" DefaultValue="Listname" />
<ext:RecordField Name="recipients" AllowBlank="false" DefaultValue="Listmembers" />
<ext:RecordField Name="usage" AllowBlank="true" />
<ext:RecordField Name="responsible" AllowBlank="false" DefaultValue="please add Responsible Person(s)/ Group(s)" />
```

Firebug console gives following error:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list
[Break On This Error]     
...,name:"responsible",defaultValue:please add Responsible Person(s)/ Group(s)}]}),...
---------------------------------------------|
admin.aspx (line 16, col 60)
```

It looks as if the Default Value is not correctly quoted as String, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the default Value of a Record Field is generally supposed to be a javascript variable.
 double-quoting it `defaultValue="'foo bar'"` fixes the problem